# IP address whitelist to update WordPress core and plugins

Tags: core, ip

I'm working on a site based on a host with quite strict firewall rules. It won't allow anything running on the site to contact an external server unless its IP address is explicity whitelisted, and I have to send these addresses to the hosting company by email.

Akismet provide a convenient list of their safe IP addresses [here](http://blog.akismet.com/akismet-hosting-faq/), which has allowed me to get that working. However I haven't been able to find an equivalent list of addresses to allow updating of the WordPress core via wp-admin or access to the WordPress plugins directory. (I can still make manual uploads by FTP.)

Does anyone know where to find a whitelist, or can you tell be the IP address(es) of the WordPress core updater and plugin directory?

Thanks

Comment: With a quick DNS lookup I found `66.155.40.202`, `66.155.40.203`, `66.155.40.249`, `66.155.40.250` not an official source but may be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for those. I've left those with the hosting people, who will make the changes when they see fit. Fingers crossed...

Comment: Sure would be great to get an official answer from WordPress.org on this. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would look at finding the IP address of the Wordpress website.

For example, downloading bbpress manually gives me the link https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/bbpress.2.5.8.zip which when using ping in command prompt gives me the IP address of

66.155.40.188 (this matches the subdomain of downloads.wordpress.com)

I would whitelist the IPs found by @gmazzap as I found them too, however the download section as a different subdomain could and seems to be a different server.

I expect that when we update through the WP admin, that it essentially sends the link through to this same location.